What are the rewards for getting all G Ranks and Star Medals?
The patch notes for Balloon Slider Mania v1.0 mention the addition of completion rewards for getting G Ranks and Star Medals on every level. What is the reward for getting every G Rank and Star Medal?

Getting star medals on all 9 tracks in Time Trial mode earns a cosmetic Wing Cap for Mario, while getting G Rank on every track unlocks Gold Mario.
Additionally, the first time you complete the bonus stage Cornersoft Parade, you will unlock the ability to play as Elise.



